# Private or Public Image Setting for Autoscale in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to set Operating System for autoscale.

In case of Operating System, I have set the code with API below.

```
        /**
         * Operating System
         */
        String operatingSystem = "WIN_2012-STD-R2_64";
virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode(operatingSystem);
```

It works fine with Operating system, but what about private or public image ?

```
            /**
             * Public Image
             */
            String GlobalIdentifier = "1176d22b-176a-499a-8d94-f9aaf29155a3";
virtualGuestMemberTemplate.setGlobalIdentifier(GlobalIdentifier);
```

It returns an error, invalid guest template. 
How can I set VirtualGuestMemberTemplate for public and private Image ?

[image: Select Operating system]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep in mind that the configuration of the VM in autoscale group is almost the same like the configuiration when you create a new VM using the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject so to set the image template you need to do it like this:

```
{ 
    "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": { 
        "globalIdentifier": "07beadaa-1e11-476e-a188-3f7795feb9fb" 
    } 
}
```

see http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject for more information

Regards